# Embed AS3 SWF inside a AS1 Flash application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-1

Our company uses Flash software from another vendor, written in AS1.
They have a plugin ability, so you can embed other SWF files.

Now, we have written a AS3 flash app, to be used as plugin. We can visually see the SWF file, and all things on the stage. But no AS3 code actually runs.

Is there any possible way to run this AS3-written SWF in a AS1 written SWF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be impossible; SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. This means that SWF files authored in Flash 8 or Flex Builder 1.5 or earlier versions cannot load ActionScript 3.0 SWF files.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff9.html